# How can octogenarians pull out a refrigerator surrounded by walls?

Tags: discussion

I apologize, but isn't it obvious that [How can I clean the back of my fridge, without pulling out the fridge?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/21357) doesn't duplicate [How can octogenarians pull out a refrigerator surrounded by walls?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/23926)

The former assumes you can't pull out the fridge, but the latter asks about pulling out a fridge.

Answer (score 2):

If not exact duplicates, the questions are close enough that members of the community voted them to be duplicate.  Asking very similar questions will always leave someone liable to being closed as duplicate.

The more recent question also received flags as being spam.  Flags which I declined as you weren't trying to sell fridges.